# Declare module typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

```js
import {ValidatorForm, TextValidator} from "react-material-ui-form-validator";
```

There is this module. The `TextValidator` component and its `index.d.ts`view have no `label` parameter, but it is there. Please tell me how you can override `Typescript`.

> Typescript: v3.4.1 
> React.JS v16.8.6

Best wishes

Comment: Where do you expect to find the `label` parameter? For instance, do you expect that on the constructor for the `TextValidator` or one of its props?

Comment: on the constructor for the TextValidator